# prediction io - how to scale and distribute load across multiple machines

Tags: predictionio

I have successfully installed PIO on a single machine and I see that the recommendation engine works fine. However, I would like to know how I can scale up the system to distribute the load across multiple machines, and I can't find anywhere clear instructions how to do it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you hosting your machine on an amazon? I used amazon's [elastic load balancing](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) to spread requests across several predictionio servers

Comment: @alex9311 I can set multiple instances of PIO behind a load balancer, but I don't want to duplicate the events stored, instead I want to distribute both the storage and computational load among all PIO instances.

Comment: @Mister_L: Events won't be duplicated unless you have multiple `Event Servers`. For horizontal scoring -sever scaling, one should deploy models (using `pio deploy`) on multiple AWS node instances and utilize Load Balancer ([ELB](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/)) on top of it.